# Find object with value in nested array and add property

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have a data structure as below with nested arrays.  I'm trying to find the simplest way to find the calendar with `id: 3` and then add a property `show: false` to that calendar.  Either using vanilla javascript (preferable) or lodash.

```
accounts: [
    {
        name: "account1",
        calendars: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "calendar1account1"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "calendar2account1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "account2",
        calendars: [
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "calendar1account2"
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: "calendar2account2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to find the *simplest* method, you can't go wrong with a couple of nested `for` loops.

```js
const obj = {"accounts":[{"name":"account1","calendars":[{"id":1,"name":"calendar1account1"},{"id":2,"name":"calendar2account1"}]},{"name":"account2","calendars":[{"id":3,"name":"calendar1account2"},{"id":4,"name":"calendar2account2"}]}]}

const hideCalendar = (accounts, calendarId) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < accounts[i].calendars.length; j++) {
      if (accounts[i].calendars[j].id === calendarId) {
        accounts[i].calendars[j].show = false
        return // exit early to prevent unnecessary loops
      }
    }
  }
}

hideCalendar(obj.accounts, 3)
console.info(obj.accounts)
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to reduce this to just the calendars, then use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the one you want and set the `show` property (if found)

```js
const obj = {"accounts":[{"name":"account1","calendars":[{"id":1,"name":"calendar1account1"},{"id":2,"name":"calendar2account1"}]},{"name":"account2","calendars":[{"id":3,"name":"calendar1account2"},{"id":4,"name":"calendar2account2"}]}]}

const hideCalendar = (accounts, calendarId) => {
  let found = accounts.flatMap(({ calendars }) => calendars)
      .find(({ id }) => id === calendarId)

  if (found) {
    found.show = false
  }
}

hideCalendar(obj.accounts, 3)
console.info(obj)
```